# Edit a row in a dataframe R

Tags: r

Wanted to check if we can edit a row in R. For example

```
df <- head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Can we edit first row (only few column) SaY we need like below

```
new_df <- head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          500         3.5          200          0.2   New
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: If you want to selectively edit a few cells, you can type `fix(new_df)` into the console and manually change some values.

Comment: Or you can do it in code, e.g., `iris[1, 1] <- 500`, or `iris$Species[1] <- "New"` (though you'll need to edit the levels of a `factor` like species or convert it to `character` class.

Comment: Or you can do: `new_df[1, c("Sepal.Length")] <- "500"` and `new_df[1, c("Petal.Length")] <- "200"` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexing to replace the numbers, like this:

```r
df <- head(iris)
df[1, c(1, 3)] <- c(500, 200)
df
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1        500.0         3.5        200.0         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Replacing a factor is a little more involved:

```r
df$Species <- factor(c("New", as.character(df$Species)[-1]))
df
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1        500.0         3.5        200.0         0.2     New
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```